# List files only in rpm package

Tags: text-processing, rpm

Launching `rpm -ql <somerpm>` lists files and directories contained in an rpm package. I am interested in only listing the files strictly speaking, not the directories.

Is there any flag or command that doesn't rely on checking each of the `rpm -ql <somerpm>` output individually whether it is a directory (as in performing a `[ -d $line ]` test in the shell on each line)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that `rpm` has no builtin option to suppress directories in the file list output.

However, you can use the `--queryformat` option (without `-l`) to print file modes and file names for each file, and then pipe the output to e.g. `grep` to exclude those entries whose mode field starts with `d`:

```shell
rpm -q --qf '[%{FILEMODES:perms} %{FILENAMES}\n]' some_rpm | grep -v '^d'
```

This would still print the mode fields of those entries that are actual files. In order to suppress that, you can use a slightly more complex `sed` program instead:

```shell
rpm -q --qf '[%{FILEMODES:perms} %{FILENAMES}\n]' some_rpm | sed -nE '/^[^d]/s/.* //p'
```

This will suppress output by default, consider only those lines that do *not* start with `d`, and remove the first column.

---

**Previous version of the answer**

However, you can use the fact that the  verbose output will print an `ls -l` style list of the files, and pipe the output to e.g. `grep` to exclude those entries whose permissions field starts with `d`:

```shell
rpm -ql -v some_rpm | grep -v '^d'
```

Note that this will still retain the "full" output style. If you want to restrict the output to the actual filename, you could pipe the output to a slightly more complex `awk` program that will only print the last column, which is the actual filename. I have included a check to see if the file is a symlink, identified by `->` as next-to-last column, in which case it will print the link name instead of the link target:

```
rpm -ql -v some_rpm | awk '$1 !~ /^d/ {if ($(NF-1) != "->") {print $NF;} else {print $(NF-2)}}'
```

This will, however, stumble upon [filenames with whitespace in it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/377345), so you need to be careful here.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of options to restrict the output:

```
-c, --configfiles
  List only configuration files (implies -l).

-d, --docfiles
  List only documentation files (implies -l).
```

But nothing for all files (and *only* files) from what I can see. So, similar to [AdminBee's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/772903/70524), I'd suggest processing the output, but instead using the `--dump` option:

```
--dump  Dump file information as follows:

   path size mtime md5sum mode owner group isconfig isdoc rdev symlink

This option must be used with at least one of -l, -c, -d.
```

Inspecting the output of an example package (like `bash`), the `md5sum`s of both directories and symlinks are all zeros, but if the entry isn't for a symlink, the last column is `X`. So:

- To print only directories:

  ```
  rpm -q -l --dump package | awk '$4 ~ /^0+$/ && $NF == "X" {print $1}'
  ```
- To print only symlinks:

  ```
  rpm -q -l --dump package | awk '$4 ~ /^0+$/ && $NF != "X" {print $1}'
  ```
- To print only files:

  ```
  rpm -q -l --dump package | awk '$4 !~ /^0+$/ && $NF == "X" {print $1}'
  ```

Example output from an Amazon Linux 2023 Docker Image:

```console
$ rpm -q bash -l --dump | awk '$4 !~ /^0+$/ && $NF == "X" {print $1}' | head # Limiting output for regular files
/etc/skel/.bash_logout
/etc/skel/.bash_profile
/etc/skel/.bashrc
/usr/bin/alias
/usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/bashbug-64
/usr/bin/bg
/usr/bin/cd
/usr/bin/command
/usr/bin/fc

$ rpm -q bash -l --dump | awk '$4 ~ /^0+$/ && $NF != "X" {print $1}'  # Symlinks
/usr/bin/bashbug
/usr/bin/sh
/usr/lib/.build-id/f2/caf7678bcb7e7d116f91109985f2f0209e714b
/usr/share/man/man1/bashbug-64.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz

$ rpm -q bash -l --dump | awk '$4 ~ /^0+$/ && $NF == "X" {print $1}' # directories
/usr/lib/.build-id
/usr/lib/.build-id/f2
/usr/share/doc/bash
/usr/share/licenses/bash
```

---

Looking at it a bit more, the `mode` also works: it seems that the mode starts with `04` (e.g., `040755`) for directories and `012` (e.g., `0120777`) for symlinks, and `010` for regular files, so that could be used instead. So, for example, to print directories:

```
rpm -q -l --dump package | awk '$(NF - 6) ~ /^04/ {print $1}'
```

Or to list files:

```
rpm -q -l --dump package | awk '$(NF - 6) ~ /^010/ {print $1}'
```

Answer (score 2):

libarchive as used by `bsdtar`, `bsdcpio` and many graphical archive extractors supports RPM files, so you could for instance use `bsdtar` to convert the RPM to `tar` format on the fly and use `star` to filter archive members by type using its `-find` option:

```
bsdtar cf - @file.rpm | star tf - -find ! -type d
```

To exclude files of type `d`irectory or `-type f` instead of `! -type f` to only include *regular* files, excluding all other types of files including directories, symlinks, devices, fifos...

Or, since GNU `tar` appends a `/` to the end of directories in its listing, if you can guarantee the RPM doesn't have members with newline in their paths:

```
bsdtar cf - @file.rpm | tar tf - | grep -v '/$'
```